# Strange return value "134" to call Gawk in a Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I met a very very strange issue when using [Gawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations) in a Bash script.

In this script, I use a function to do some text processing. Even a very simple Gawk command will return error 134.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 testFunc()
 {
   log "Before gawk: $?"
   gawk '{print}' file
   log "After gawk: $?"
 }
```

If I manually run this script in console, it will work perfectly. `$?` will always be 0 which means success, but if I use this script as a Linux startup script in *etc/rc.d/* for level 3, after Gawk is executed, the `$?` is always `134`. What's the meaning of 134?

If I replace `gawk '{print}' file` to `gawk --version`, the result is OK. $? is 0.

Comment: This would imply that the previous command did not execute successfully.

Comment: No, if i replace "gawk '{print}' file" to "gawk --version", the result is ok, $? is 0

Comment: What is the content of `file`?

Comment: the content of file is like below:
abc,1,2[new line]
def,3,4

Answer (score 44):

Exit code 134 means your program was aborted (received SIGABRT), perhaps as a result of a failed assertion.

(As @hobbs has explained in the comment below, you subtract 128 from the exit code to map to SIGABRT in list.)
You may need give the full path of command `log` and full path of `file`.

Here is the signal list by command `kill`:

```
kill -l

 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL
 5) SIGTRAP      6) SIGABRT      7) SIGEMT       8) SIGFPE
 9) SIGKILL     10) SIGBUS      11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGSYS
13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM     16) SIGUSR1
17) SIGUSR2     18) SIGCHLD     19) SIGPWR      20) SIGWINCH
21) SIGURG      22) SIGIO       23) SIGSTOP     24) SIGTSTP
25) SIGCONT     26) SIGTTIN     27) SIGTTOU     28) SIGVTALRM
29) SIGPROF     30) SIGXCPU     31) SIGXFSZ     32) SIGWAITING
33) SIGLWP      34) SIGFREEZE   35) SIGTHAW     36) SIGCANCEL
37) SIGLOST     38) SIGXRES     41) SIGRTMIN    42) SIGRTMIN+1
43) SIGRTMIN+2  44) SIGRTMIN+3  45) SIGRTMAX-3  46) SIGRTMAX-2
47) SIGRTMAX-1  48) SIGRTMAX
```

Comment: For those curious, the status code is 128 plus the signal that was caught. 134 - 128 = 6. Signal 6 is `SIGABRT`.

Comment: if i replace "gawk '{print}' file" to "gawk --version", the result is ok, $? is 0, i don't know why it was aborted.

Comment: @mailzyok,  I have asked to check `You may need give the full path of command log and full path of file`

Comment: Thanks. In the real script, this file path is like "/private/data/data.txt". I don't know why you need the path of command log, it is an internal function, there should be no problem.

Comment: i tried gawk 'BEGIN {print "abc"}' which don't require a file, it didn't work either, still 134 was returned, only i tried gawk --version, 0 is returned

Comment: my gawk version is GNU Awk 3.1.8

Comment: is the folder /private mounted separated or not? Looks like it is in  different filesystem.

Comment: /private is mounted nfs

Comment: can you copy the data.txt file to root or to /var/tmp, and check if you still get this error or not?

Comment: @BMW, Have you seen my previous comment? i tried gawk 'BEGIN {print "abc"}' which don't require a file, it didn't work either, still 134 was returned,

Comment: Thank you, This is great! I also found this to further explain linux exit codes - http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Answer (score 1):

One situation in C++ code is when the code throws an exception that is not handled. For example:

```
if (someval > 10) {
    throw runtime_error("number too large");
}
```

The binary containing this code when executed and encountered this situation will get exit status 134, at least in my situation: the operating system is [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS).