# Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have a small piece of code, which I cannot run in pycharm virtual environment

```
INPUT_FILE_PATH = './data/'
# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print_hi('PyCharm')
    print('loading data ... ')
    hemo_filename = INPUT_FILE_PATH + 'hemo_ALl_seq.txt'
    hemo_data = np.loadtxt(hemo_filename, delimiter='\t', skiprows=1, dtype=str)
```

It shows the following error and ends the running:
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

```
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

what could be the reason?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48313226/18054760) could be useful to you

Comment: I suppose `np.loadtxt` is loading the file into memory and it's too large for the memory PyCharm makes available. See [one of these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpycharm%5D+signal+6%3A+SIGABRT&searchOn=3) but I'm pretty sure this is more of a NumPy issue than a problem caused by the IDE.

Comment: Can you run it *outside* of pycharm (say from a terminal or cmd window) without error? If yes, it's a pycharm problem. If no, the problem is in your code.

Comment: Have you found a suitable answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on a xubuntu machine.

Installing a JRE solved it for me. I followed this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-22-04).

Installing Oracle JDK was not necessary. I installed `default-jre` and `default-jdk` and set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable + reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a stack overflow; check your code for infinite recursions. Here's a minimal code example to reproduce:

```py
import asyncio


async def foo():
    await foo()

asyncio.run(foo())
```

This results in:

```
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6:SIGABRT)
```