# Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT) in Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

Consider:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm using Python and OpenCV in the [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm) IDE. When I try to open the webcam using OpenCV, it gives the following error:

> Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Is this happening because I'm running out of memory?
What are the solutions for this?

I'm using PyCharm on MacBook Pro (OS: [macOS v10.14 (Mojave)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave)).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290403/process-finished-with-exit-code-134-interrupted-by-signal-6-sigabrt

Comment: @Eskapp above issue is happening because of apple refuse to give permission to access the webcam is there any other solutions to this issue?

Comment: [The underlying reason may be an assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098695/strange-return-value-134-to-call-gawk-in-bash-script/23098735#23098735). 134 is most certainly a very common exit code for [asserts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)#Assertions_for_run-time_checking).

Answer (score 4):

1. Open /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/info.plist,
2. Insert a new line:

   - Key: Privacy - Camera Usage
   - Type: String
   - Value: An application in PyCharm wants to use the camera.
3. Save it.
4. Reopen PyCharm.
5. Run your code.

Comment: That is included in the actual version of PyCharm, but it still does not work!

Answer (score 2):

I have opened [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-224190) at [JetBrains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains) because of this. But here is a workaround:

Run PyCharm or [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) (whatever JetBrains application) from an application which **already** has been approved for camera access. For example, I use the [Hyper](https://hyper.is/) terminal to run the IDE and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

By running the Python script in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), it will execute the program without any warnings or bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Open file */Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/info.plist* in any text editor.

Add these two lines before the *dict* and *plist* tags:

```xml
        <key>Privacy - Camera Usage</key>
        <string>An application in PyCharm wants to use the camera.</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```