# cv2.VideoCapture(0).read() returns (False, None)

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)#width
cap.set(4,480)#height
cap.set(10,100)#brightness
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    print(img)#getting None
    print(success)#getting False
    cv2.imshow("video", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    if 0xFF == ord('q') :
        break
```

VideoCapture worked well with an mp4 video. But when I tried to use it for my laptop webcam it doesn't work.
Running this code for the first-time on my laptop using pyCharm.
At first, the webcam itself was not opening. So, I checked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57230407/process-finished-with-exit-code-134-interrupted-by-signal-6-sigabrt-in-python) and added the following in /Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/Contents/Info.plist

```
<key>Privacy - Camera Usage</key>
<string>An application in PyCharm wants to use the camera</string>
```

After the webcam is getting started when I run the code but imshow is returning None.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sreeharsha/PycharmProjects/OpencvPython/chapter1.py", line 26, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("video", img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-4jcifzim/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

cap.isOpened() is returning True
When I try cap.getBackendName() it returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sreeharsha/PycharmProjects/OpencvPython/chapter1.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(cap.getBackendName())
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-4jcifzim/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp:299: error: (-215:Assertion failed) api != 0 in function 'getBackendName'
```

cv2.getBuildInformation() is as follows

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.4.0 =====================================
  Version control:               4.4.0-dirty

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2020-09-22T21:19:42Z
    Host:                        Darwin 17.7.0 x86_64
    CMake:                       3.18.2
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1
      requested:                 DETECT
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (29 files):           + POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (4 files):      + POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/local/opt/ccache/libexec/clang++  (ver 9.1.0.9020039)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/local/opt/ccache/libexec/clang
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -Qunused-arguments -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,-dead_strip  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,-dead_strip  
    ccache:                      YES
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          -framework OpenCL /Applications/Xcode-9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework -lm -ldl ade Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent openjp2
    3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf zlib libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff IlmImf quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java js python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI: 
    QT:                          YES (ver 5.13.2)
      QT OpenGL support:         NO
    Cocoa:                       YES
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.5-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   OpenJPEG (ver 2.3.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.91.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.45.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.51.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.7.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    AVFoundation:                YES

  Parallel framework:            GCD

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-4jcifzim/_skbuild/macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_mac/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-4jcifzim/_skbuild/macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_mac/iw
    Lapack:                      YES (/Applications/Xcode-9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework -lm -ldl)
    Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.7)
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                NO
    Link libraries:              -framework OpenCL

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/venv/bin/python (ver 3.7.8)
    Libraries:                   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libpython3.7m.dylib (ver 3.7.8)
    numpy:                       /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-build-env-0spssg56/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.14.5)
    install path:                python

  Python (for build):            /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         /Applications/Xcode-9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers /Applications/Xcode-9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers /Applications/Xcode-9.4.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-4jcifzim/_skbuild/macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also tried to create VideoCapture using various apiPreferences, but all of them failed.

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_V4L2)
```

Please help me understand why this issue occurs and how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the frame is being read correctly also according to [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15384) try vidcap like in the following code snippet:

```
import cv2
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_V4L)
cap.set(3,640)#width
cap.set(4,480)#height
cap.set(10,100)#brightness
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    if success:
        print(img)#getting None
        print(success)#getting False
        cv2.imshow("video", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        if 0xFF == ord('q') :
            break
```

Comment: I am always getting success as False. So, the frame is not getting read correctly. What would be the reason?

Comment: Does this help   if not success: ?

Comment: The most common reason for the frame not being successfully read is that the path to it is not correct, you should check its path again and make sure that it is correct.

Comment: Could also be permissions related. On my Windows 11 system, under Privacy & Security >Camera , enabling Let apps access your camera>Let desktop apps access your camera worked, without enabling this is was also getting False , None